# "RuntimeException: Cannot create handler inside the thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
`//some method
Timer timer=new Timer();
    //Handler handler=new Handler();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            loadLayout();
        }

    }, 1000, 10000000);
 //end of method
 public void loadLayout()
 {
    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY |        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.locked_layout, null);
    wm.addView(myview, params);
 }`
```

How to call WindowMananger.addView(viewGroup,layoutParams) method within a thread?
Please help me!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you are calling WindowMananger.addView(viewGroup,layoutParams) in separate thread, you should call it in UI-thread. This code is in Activity, right? So just modify your TimerTask:

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
//Handler handler=new Handler();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {       
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
             loadLayout();
          }
      });
    }

}, 1000, 10000000);
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'm running it in a service. It doesnt have runOnUiThread method. Is there any method to invoke it from the service?